# ASP.NET MVC value of multiple input tag into a sql query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to filter my table using multiple input tag, base on the picture, something like: "SELECT * FROM tbltransactions WHERE ammount > 30000 AND percent > 500 AND inside the From and To date" I only know how to filter one, but not multiple, i don't know how to make the Filter button get all the values at once

[image: Sample Picture]

Sample Table:

```
Id-----relation2ammount-----amount-----relation2percentage-----percentage-----date
1------>--------------------12000------>-----------------------500------------4/06/2017
2------>--------------------4000------->-----------------------500------------2/13/2017
```

SelectModel.cs

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class SelectModel
    {
        private static SqlConnection GetCn()
        {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"MyConnectionString");
        return cn;
        }

        public DataSet FilterTransactions(string txtamt)
        {
        SqlConnection cn = GetCn();
        string sqlquery = "";
        if(txtamt != null)
        {
            sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM tbltransactions WHERE ammount = '" + txtamt + "' ORDER BY Id ASC";
        }
        else
        {
            sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM tbltransactions ORDER BY Id ASC";
        }
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

MyProjectViewModel.cs

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class MyProjectViewModel
    {
        public DataTable Transactions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    public ActionResult Index(MyProject.Models.SelectModel selectmodel, string txtAmount)
    {
        MyProjectViewModel vm = new MyProjectViewModel();
        DataSet ds = selectmodel.FilterTransactions(txtAmount);
        vm.Transactions = ds.Tables[0];

        return View(vm);
    }
    }
}
```

Index.chtml

```
@model MyProject.Models.MyProjectViewModel

<label class="control-label">Amount:</label>
<select id="rel2amt" class="form-control">
    <option>Greater than</option>
    <option>Less than</option>
    <option>Greater than or Equal to</option>
    <option>Less than or Equal to</option>
    <option>Equal</option>
</select>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
<input id="txtamnt" type="text" class="form-control">
}

<label class="control-label">Percent:</label>
<select id="rel2pcent" class="form-control">
    <option>Greater than</option>
    <option>Less than</option>
    <option>Greater than or Equal to</option>
    <option>Less than or Equal to</option>
    <option>Equal</option>
</select>
<input id="txtpcent" type="text" class="form-control">

<label class="control-label">From:</label>
<input id="txtfrom" type="text" class="form-control" disabled>

<label class="control-label">To:</label>
<input id="txtto" type="text" class="form-control" disabled>

<button id="btnfilter" class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Filter</button>
```

Comment: First Google `SQL Injection`.  Second, Google `SQL WHERE clause`.

Comment: Third, Google `c# using statement`

Comment: Fourth, why is your Controller receiving both a Model and a string and then ignores completely the Model? The Model should have all the data you need from the View

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's very simple, if the base concept is clear.

**In Short:**

That is in the controller action method, you can get all the view formfield values by using the name of the control as a key value pair.

So in your case, as a first thing in a view, put all your control inside the form tag as below:

**Index.chtml**

```
@model MyProject.Models.MyProjectViewModel

<label class="control-label">Amount:</label>
<select id="rel2amt" class="form-control">
    <option>Greater than</option>
    <option>Less than</option>
    <option>Greater than or Equal to</option>
    <option>Less than or Equal to</option>
    <option>Equal</option>
</select>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
<input id="txtamnt" type="text" class="form-control">

//put inside the form
<label class="control-label">Percent:</label>
<select id="rel2pcent" class="form-control">
    <option>Greater than</option>
    <option>Less than</option>
    <option>Greater than or Equal to</option>
    <option>Less than or Equal to</option>
    <option>Equal</option>
</select>
<input id="txtpcent" type="text" class="form-control">

<label class="control-label">From:</label>
<input id="txtfrom" type="text" class="form-control" disabled>

<label class="control-label">To:</label>
<input id="txtto" type="text" class="form-control" disabled>

<button id="btnfilter" class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Filter</button>

}
```

In a controller Action Method:

```
public ActionResult Index(MyProject.Models.SelectModel selectmodel, string txtAmount,string txtpcent,.....)
    {
        MyProjectViewModel vm = new MyProjectViewModel();
        DataSet ds = selectmodel.FilterTransactions(txtAmount);
        vm.Transactions = ds.Tables[0];

        return View(vm);
    }
```

Note: If the parameters of the action method became too big  , and if you dont want to do that then you can get the same values using request.form["name"].

Example:

```
public ActionResult Index(MyProject.Models.SelectModel selectmodel, string txtAmount)
        {
           string percentvalue = Request.Form["txtpcent"];   

            //here add as many request.form we want.  
            MyProjectViewModel vm = new MyProjectViewModel();
            DataSet ds = selectmodel.FilterTransactions(txtAmount);
            vm.Transactions = ds.Tables[0];

            return View(vm);
        }
```

Finally, put those values to your select query and get the expected output.